# How to disabled autocomplete input type password? not worknig autocomplete="off"

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Hello autocomplete on google chrome doesn't work for me. What is another way to turn off autocomplets for password field ??
I am using Vue

Comment: Hello @TEet, please read carefully this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't write a question with a chat syntax.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use "form" tag in your form field and set autocomplete for both of form and password input tags.

```html
<form action="" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="username">username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
  <label for="pass">Last name:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```